# create a UI Menu with scrolling

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function within my google apps script, that pulls a list of "Events" from a database, and uses the list to create a new Menu, called "Run Event Report". From that Menu I expect to run the event report for that Event.

The relevant function is here:

```
function getEventsList(){  
  Logger.clear();

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var urls = urlBuilder();

  var token = getToken(ui, urls.getAuthServiceUrl());
  var accountId = getDataFromApi(urls.getAccountsListUrl(), token)[0].Id;
  var EventsCount = getDataFromApi(urls.getEventsCountUrl(accountId), token);
  var EventList = getDataFromApi(urls.getEventsListUrl(accountId), token);

  var menu = ui.createMenu('Run Event Report')

  for (var y = 0; y < EventsCount.Count-1; y++) {
    var name = EventList.Events[y].Name;
    var startDate = EventList.Events[y].StartDate;
    var str = name + " (" + startDate.slice(0,10) + ")";

    menu.addItem(str, 'runEventReport(' + y + ')');
  }
  menu.addToUi();

}
```

The problem is, the created menu is longer than the screen height, and there appears to be no scrolling ability. So I cannot access the items further down the menu.

Any idea if it is possible to enable scrolling within Google Apps Script created menus?

Comment: It would probably be cleaner to use the menu to open a sidebar that lists all the reports you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while and having this issue before I don't think it is designed to offer lots of menu items in one menu; however, you could add a loop inside this / if statement and put them into sub menu items like a nested list. 
It explains how the sub menu item works here:[Google Menu Item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addSeparator()).

If you want an example of how this could be done let me know and I will put an example into here for you.

Hope that helps.

Good Luck :)